# SVProgressHUD - user interation disabled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm using SVProgressHUD in my app.

After calling `[SVProgressHUD dismissWithSuccess:@"blabla"];`, I'm not able to interact with my app anymore. I need to restart it in order to fix the user interaction problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you manually changing the alpha anywhere?

Comment: I'm using maskType SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGardient to dim the background. One of its advantages is that it's disable the user interaction while displaying the loader. The problem is, it's not enabling the user interaction...

Comment: I think I've come across your username on GitHub. You submitted an issue about this right? Hasn't it been fixed since?

Comment: Yeah it has been fixed. This issue was opened after I've opened it on github :)

Answer (score 1):

You must use ARC on HUD, add `-fobjc-arc`

Comment: +1 @blackgun to clarify -  this flag is set on the SVProgressHUD.m file in the Compile Sources list on the Targets 'Build Phases'